# HTML on press enter trigger a button

Tags: html

I want to tigger the button `name=buttonexecute` when ever user press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. Can some one help me in this pls.

```
<div class="mytext1" style="height: 40px;">
    <br>
    <form id="myform" method="post" style="font-size: 22px">Text :
        <input type="text" id="search_text" name="search_text" size="44" autofocus>Extension :
        <input type="text" id="search_extension" name="search_extension" size="4" maxlength="4">&nbsp; Sub Files
        <input type="checkbox" id="subfolder" name="subfolder" value="0">&nbsp;&nbsp; LTO-No.
        <input type="text" id="search_ltono" name="search_ltono" size="4" maxlength="4">&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input name="buttonExecute" id="endereco" 
               type="button" value="Show&nbsp;&nbsp;"
               onclick="ajaxFunction(search_text.value,search_ltono.value,search_extension.value)" 
               autofocus>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add some code to the question with your problem?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, since you are using inline onclick handler on `buttonExecute` button, you an then do something like this:

```
document.getElementById('myform').onkeyup = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        document.getElementById('endereco').onclick();
        // or: ajaxFunction(search_text.value, search_ltono.value, search_extension.value)
    }
}
```

**Proper way**. But what you should really do is to use `onsubmit` event and use button type `submit`. Then instead of this shenanigans with <kbd>Enter</kbd> key events you could use this:

```
<form id="myform" method="post" onsubmit="ajaxFunction(search_text.value,search_ltono.value,search_extension.value)">
    <!-- ... -->
    <input name="buttonExecute" id="endereco" 
           type="submit" value="Show&nbsp;&nbsp;" 
           autofocus>
</form>
```

`onsubmit` event is fired on submit button clicks and <kbd>Enter</kbd> keys, exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with the following.

```
function searchKeyPress(e)
{
    // look for window.event in case event isn't passed in
    if (typeof e == 'undefined' && window.event) { e = window.event; }
    if (e.keyCode == 13)
    {
        document.getElementById('endereco').click();
    }
}
Text : <input type="text" onkeypress="searchKeyPress(event);" id="search_text" name="search_text" size="44"  autofocus >
<input type="text" id="search_extension" name="search_extension" onkeypress="searchKeyPress(event);" size="4" maxlength="4">
Sub Files <input type="checkbox" id="subfolder" name="subfolder" onkeypress="searchKeyPress(event);" value="0">
LTO-No. <input type="text" id="search_ltono" name="search_ltono" onkeypress="searchKeyPress(event);" size="4" maxlength="4">
```

This works fine.